# the query is not using an index despite the columns joined are of the same type

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query is taking too long and as the execution plan suggests it is scanning over a million rows on SPC and not using an index. I would like to understand if there is way to either use the index or modify the query to avoid searching through that amount of data.

```
mysql> explain extended select *
    -> from (((((((`raw`.`HUB_PA` `HP`
    -> left
    -> join `raw`.`SAT_TABLE1` `SPD` on(((`HP`.`P_HA` = `SPD`.`P_HA`) and (`SPD`.`ENDS_ON` = str_to_date('31/12/9999','%d/%m/%Y')))))
    -> join `raw`.`LINK_TABLE1` `LPR` on((`LPR`.`P_HA` = `HP`.`P_HA`))) join `raw`.`PA_ROLE` `HR` on(((`LPR`.`PA_ROLE_HA` = `HR`.`P_ROLE_HASH`) and (`HR`.`PARTY_ROLE` = 'CUSTOMER'))))
    -> join `raw`.`LINK_TABLE2` `LPC` on((`LPC`.`P_HA` = `HP`.`P_HA`))) join `raw`.`H_LOC` `HL` on((`HL`.`LOC_HA` = `LPC`.`LOC_HA`)))
    -> join `raw`.`SAT_TABLE2` `SPC` on(((`SPC`.`PCH` = `LPC`.`PCH`) and (`SPC`.`ENDS_ON` = str_to_date('31/12/9999','%d/%m/%Y')))))
    -> join `raw`.`SAT_TABLE3` `SPA` on((`SPA`.`LOC_HA` = `LPC`.`LOC_HA`)));
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                       | key               | key_len | ref             | rows    | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | HR    | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY                             | NULL              | NULL    | NULL            |       7 |    14.29 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | SPC   | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY,SAT_CONTACT_INDEX           | NULL              | NULL    | NULL            | 1318796 |    10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | LPC   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,LINK_CP_INDEX,LINK_PC_INDEX | PRIMARY           | 32      | raw.SPC.PCH     |       1 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | HL    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                             | PRIMARY           | 32      | raw.LPC.LOC_HA  |       1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | SPA   | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,SAT_ADDRESS_INDEX           | SAT_ADDRESS_INDEX | 32      | raw.LPC.LOC_HA  |       1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | HP    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                             | PRIMARY           | 32      | raw.LPC.P_HA    |       1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | SPD   | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,SAT_DETAILS_INDEX           | PRIMARY           | 32      | raw.LPC.P_HA    |       1 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | LPR   | NULL       | ref    | LINK_ROLE_INDEX                     | LINK_ROLE_INDEX   | 33      | raw.LPC.P_HA    |       1 |    10.00 | Using where                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.02 sec)



| SAT_TABLE2 | CREATE TABLE `SAT_TABLE2` (
  `CANCEL_FROM_MAILING` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CDC_HPC` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STARTS_FROM` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENDS_ON` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOAD_DATETIME` datetime NOT NULL,
  `PCH` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `SOURCE_SYSTEM` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PCH`,`LOAD_DATETIME`),
  KEY `SAT_CONTACT_INDEX` (`PCH`),
  KEY `SAT_CONTACT_CDC_INDEX` (`CDC_HASH_PARTY_CONTACT`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

| PA_ROLE| CREATE TABLE `HUB_PARTY_ROLE` (
  `LOAD_DATETIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `PA_ROLE_HA` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `PARTY_ROLE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SOURCE_SYSTEM` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PARTY_ROLE_HASH`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: What is `SPC`? Where is the definition for the other tables? All those tables have index? Try to join two tables and see if you are using index, and then add one table each time to find where is the problem

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza SPC is an alias (check out the query), which stands for SAT_TABLE2 table. From the other tables max HR (PA_ROLE) may be of interest, since that's the other one where no index is used. For all other tables index is used for joining, therefore their structure is not that relevant.

Comment: Have you tried using an index hint for SPC table?

Comment: @Shadow thanks, I have added the create statement for PA_ROLE

Comment: @Shadow how do I use index hint in mysql?

Comment: @ranj1185 hint: type MySQL index hint into google, and you will know a lot more about MySQL index hints :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have index for `SPC`.`ENDS_ON`

You should create a composite index for `SAT_TABLE2( PCH, ENDS_ON)`

Comment: @ Juan Carlos Oropeza thanks , that has increased the speed and the row count was a lot lower when looking at the explain plan

Comment: remember accept the answer as correct if help solve your problem